# How can I test a GameKit dependent app with KIF?

Tags: ios, integration-testing, gamekit, kif

I'm in the beginning stages of an iOS game that requires GameKit in order to play. I'm comfortable with [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) for integration testing and have used it on various projects.

However, since this app requires GameKit there isn't much I can test without GameKit (e.g. GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController) interaction. Ideally I wouldn't even need to test the UI once the user is setting up the match since I don't want to be responsible for testing GameKit view controllers. Also, using the Accessibility Inspector I've found that GameKit view controllers might be difficult to test. I'd like to have zero dependency on the game center service since the sandbox is notoriously flaky.

Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

`[tester stepsForCreatingTurnBasedMatchWithPlayers:players];`

but that steps implementation would require digging into the app to find a GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate and explicitly call methods on it. This is the very first issue I've come across as I'm sure there are numerous others.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of situation and, if so, how do you create integration tests that stay true to responding to user interaction? Am I thinking about this all wrong and should just be creating mock objects that execute appropriate callbacks (but that feels like more of a unit test solution)?

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past and implemented own classes that looked like the ones in GameKit and supported unit testing. In the end it (or at least so far) was not really worth the trouble.